# GeoFire observeReady gets executed prematurely in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, geofire

In the following function I am am performing an initial geofire search query and wish to process all keys found, append them to an array and send the entire array back.

The issue is that the `observeReady` block of code is being executed too prematurely and therefore sending an empty array (nothing displays at first load even though there are keys found within the range).

I understand that the `observeSingleEvent` call is `asynchronous` and may be causing this behaviour, so my question is, how can I manage this and ensure that the keys are processed prior to executing the `handler` call within the `observeReady` block?

```
func fetchInitialNearbyVenues(deviceLocation: CLLocation, radius: Double, handler: @escaping ([Venue]) -> ()) {

        self.venuesArray.removeAll() 
        var savedByUsers = [String : String]() 

        let query = self.GEOFIRE_VENUES_LOC.query(at: deviceLocation, withRadius: radius) 

            query.observe(.keyEntered) { (key: String!, venueLocation: CLLocation!) in 

                self.REF_VENUES.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in 

                  //process snapshot create and append Venue object to array
                  //...
                  //...

                  self.venuesArray.append(venue) //append Venue to array

                })//end observeSingleEvent

            }//end geofire query observe

        query.observeReady {
            handler(self.venuesArray) //PROBLEM: This gets executed prematurely thus sending an empty array via handler 
        }

    }//end func
```

Comment: The `.keyEntered` for `query` is supposed to be called for each key in `query` before `observeReady` is called. Are you saying that is not the case for you?

Comment: what I'm saying is that `observeReady` is **being called before** `keyEntered` for `query` has finished fetching the data from Firebase and appending the `Venue` object to the array for all `keys` found within the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is expected behavior. The `observeReady` is guaranteed to fire after all the corresponding `observe(.keyEntered)` have been called. You can verify this with some simple logging statements:

```
query.observe(.keyEntered) { (key: String!, venueLocation: CLLocation!) in 
   print(".keyEntered")
}
query.observeReady {
   print(".observeReady")
}
```

When you run this it will print:

> .keyEntered
>
> .keyEntered
>
> ...
>
> .observeReady

That is in line with how the API is supposed to work. But in the `.keyEntered` you are loading additional data from Firebase, which happens asynchronously. And those calls may indeed complete *after* the `.observeReady` has fired.

So you will need to implement the necessary synchronization yourself. A simple way to detect if you have loaded all the additional data, is to keep a count of all the keys for which you still need to load data. So you `+1` that every time you add a key, and `-1` every time you've loaded the venue data:

```
let venuesToLoadCount = 0
query.observe(.keyEntered) { (key: String!, venueLocation: CLLocation!) in 
   venuesToLoadCount = venuesToLoadCount + 1
   self.REF_VENUES.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in     
        venuesToLoadCount = venuesToLoadCount - 1
        if venuesToLoadCount == 0 {
            print("All done")
        }
    }
}
query.observeReady {
    if venuesToLoadCount == 0 {
        print("All done")
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah - this worked after I attempted to implement your answer for the second time. I had the `if venuesToLoad == 0 {...}` in the wrong side of the curly bracket. :)